# "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am getting this error in firebug:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

From this code:

```
table +=
'<tbody>'+
  '<tr>'+
  '<td>'+this.zona+'</td>' +
  '<td>'+this.rruga+'<br/><div id="dialog-'+this.id+'" style= "margin-left:1px; width:340px; display:none;height:180px"></div></td>' +
  '<td>'+this.dita+'</td>' +
  '<td><img src="images/map.jpg"  id = "mapicon" onClick="show(this.rruga, this.id);"></td>' +
'<tr>'+
'<tbody>';
```

I am not quite sure which parenthesis `)` is missing in my code.

Comment: Your string concatenation doesn't make sense.

Comment: in fact your string concatenation is not concatenating

Comment: `onClick="show(this.rruga,this.id);"`

Comment: There does not seem to be a syntax error. But it's surely not what you want. Either your code is different or the syntax error is thrown somewhere else.

Comment: @FelixKling I suppose we don't see enough, and that OP just pasted from some HTML generation code.

Comment: This is complete code:

Comment: I bet you it isn't. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this` inside '' . 
Moreover, you need to use `getAttribute()` in order to get `rugga`  value from the specific element.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfRLm/1/).

Comment: yes, but irrelevant here. That wouldn't explain the syntax error.

Comment: I dont see any working answer :s

Comment: post the `show` function

Comment: function show(street,id){
  
  window.alert(street + " - >"+id);
  
 }

Comment: I've replaced the `show` in the fiddle with your function, check the fiddle.

change the `<img>` according to the fiddle and see if it works for you.

Comment: No i cant get it work with your example :S, btw i noticed smth else, if i pass in function both parameters as show(' + this.id + ', ' + this.id + ') , it works this way it passes , so when i add as first parametes this.rruga as a string and it cannot pass

Comment: if I do this way

show(\'' + this.rruga + '\', ' + this.id + ')

it works for some but not for all , that's strange

Comment: You can't write this.rruga , this is not a property and you can't use it that way. , also, there's absolutely no need for '' when you passing properties (this.x) as parameters. Look at the example

Answer (score 6):

This is because of your use of `+` with your quotes. You code

```
str = '...' + 'onclick="show(' + this.rruga + ', ' + this.id + ');"' + '...';
```

will generate HTML that looks like

```
onclick="show(hello world,foo bar);"
```

This obviously won't work, as your function's arguments are no longer quoted properly, so are treated as variable names, then the spaces cause the exception to be thrown. In a worst case scenario, that you do not have `this.rruga` or `this.id` quoted or HTML encoded, someone could possibly pass a specially crafted piece of code which would inject custom HTML into the page.

You can keep using a string as long as you encode your arguments so they're HTML-safe and won't end the quotes, and then adding quotes around them them (`\'`).

HTML+JavaScript encoded quotes are `\\&quot;` for `\"` and `\\&#39;` for `\'`. The preceeding `\\` is so that it does not break the *JavaScript* quotes, then the `&foo;` is the HTML-encoding for the character.

```
str = '...' + 'onclick="show(\''
            + (''+this.rruga).replace(/"/g, '\\&quot;').replace(/'/g, '\\&#39;') + '\', \''
            + (''+this.id).replace(/"/g, '\\&quot;').replace(/'/g, '\\&#39;') + '\');"'
            + '...';
```

As you are generating all of this in *JavaScript*, consider keeping your listener out of the HTML string and attaching it to the element with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or simply `node.onclick`. This will mean you can inherit the scope of where you are in the function you want (although `this` will still change to mean the *Node*), and if you use DOM methods you have much less to worry about by way of special encoding as the browser will do the work for you.

---

**EDIT** I'll add a function to make it easy for you

```
function quoteAndEscape(str) {
    return ''
        + '&#39;'                      // open quote '
        + (''+str)                     // force string
            .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')    // double \
            .replace(/"/g, '\\&quot;') // encode "
            .replace(/'/g, '\\&#39;')  // encode '
        + '&#39;';                     // close quote '
}

quoteAndEscape('I\'ll say "hello" to the WORLD!');
// &#39;I\&#39;ll say \&quot;hello\&quot; to the WORLD!&#39;
// which is a HTML-encoded JavaScript String literal.
// You may also want to encode the opening and closing quotes
// these ones don't need to be backslash-escaped though.
// edited that too
```

Comment: Do you think this DOM element has a rruga property ?

Comment: @dystroy not by default

Comment: The `+` are just part of the string, the code itself is actually syntactically correct.

Comment: OP probably has this code in a more extended solution where this isn't the element. But what it is we can't tell.

Comment: this.rruga is comming from JSON function(data,function(){....})

Comment: This doesn't explain the syntax error.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Are you happy with the explanation now? --- Lulzim, the rest of your code would have been much appreciated when you first posted your question, as you originally posted just too little for a complete answer.

Comment: @Lulzim if you're wondering, the `(''+foo)` is to force to string so that `.replace` is defined. I did this as I don't know your data type.

Comment: I am sorry Paul, maybe ur answer is right , but I still cannot make it work :s

Comment: Thanks Paul managed to fixed with ur last update :d...

Comment: @PaulS. oh well, an upvote would have been nice to my answer, as actually I figured out what he was doing. but nevermind...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I see what you did there

Comment: Thank you for providing details.

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you posted is part of a command, so there's a preceeding `'`.

You can get this error message if `this.rruga` has special characters, for example a space.. eg: the code will create something like `show(hello there, 12);` which is syntactically incorrect. You can verify this by just checking the generated html content.

Solution: Put that argument within quotes. ...`\''+this.rruga+'\'`...